# Form.io custom validation to remove an option from a select component (drop-down menu) that has appeared in a previous select component

Tags: javascript, json, forms, drop-down-menu, io

I am using Form.io and would like a custom validation where I want to remove an option from a select component if that same option has appeared before.

Lets say we have 2 select components: **Activity1** and **Activity2**, both of which let the user choose from the same 20 activities.

If a user fills in one of the 20 listed activities for the **Activity1** Select component, I would like that activity to be removed from the **Activity2** select component.

So that the user cannot choose the same activity twice.
Any ideas?

I've been looking around the internet for a solution and have got this far:

```
var values = [];

if (data.Activity1 === 'chess') {
  value.push('chess');
} else if (data.Activity1 === 'climbing') {
  value.push('climbing');
} else if (data.Activity1 === 'fencing') {
  value.push('fencing');
}

if (!values.includes(data.option)) {
  delete data.option;
```

not sure if I'm on the right track though.